# Yii Lazy Loading From Object Instance ($this) with Criteria (Is it possible?)

Tags: object, yii, models, relationship, has-many

I'm new to Yii and used to Kohana.  I have two models:
1. sampleRequests -> (this has many SampleShares)
2. sampleShares

In my case I have already instantiated an object (sampleRequest) and I am trying to get a particular sampleShares based on added criteria.

In Kohana I could do:

```
$myShare = $this->sampleShares->where('user_id','=',$my_user_id)->find();
```

It Yii I have tried something similar:

```
$myShare = $this->sampleShares->find(array(
'condition'=>'user_id:user_id',
'params'=>array(':user_id'=>$my_user_id)));
```

The previous does not work for me however, the following will work:

```
$myShare = SampleShare::model()->find(array(
'condition'=>'sample_id=:id AND user_id=:user_id',
'params'=>array(':id'=>$this->id, ':user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->id)));
```

So my question is, can you grab related models with appended select criteria to the relationships established in Yii (particular with the instance or $this)? (Similar to my Koahana example?) If so how do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out.  I just had to replace:

```
$this->sampleShares->find(
```

with

```
$this->with('sampleShares')->find(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myShare = SampleShare::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'sample_id='.$id.' AND user_id='.$user_id));
```

and relation query example

```
$myShare = SampleShare::model()->with('sampleRequests')->findAll(array('condition'=>'sample_id='.$id.' AND user_id='.$user_id));
```

you can find the realtion name in your model file...

And then you can get the related table records using **$myShare->sampleRequests**

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this does not answer my question.  In my case the relationships are already setup. Just to clarify the situation.  There are requests and potentially multiple shares per request. I have a particular sampleRequest already instantiated ($this).  It has_many sampleRequests (that is the relationship name). The table name is (sample_request).  So my point is I want to be able to use -> $this  to get to a particular sample_request.

Answer (score 0):

you can set relationship between the tables in your model file, like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'CategoryCategory', 'category_id'),
    );
}
```

how to use:

```
$model=Blog::model()->with('category')->findAll(); //object
```